# How to access session and HTTPClient methods in Console app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, http, session

I have created a console application.

I am trying to access Session variables and use HttpClient to make Api calls.

I am not able to get Session and HttpClient classes in the namespaces.

I have added the following packages.

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net45" />
```

please let me know if i missed out any other package.I want to execute the below code.

I am getting error like:

> httpClient is a type but is used like a method.

Here is my Code:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209010/console-app-httpclient-post-to-mvc-web-api

Comment: I see no reason how you would get that error on line 2 of your code unless you have incorrect capitalisation. For Session, there is no session in a console app so you will never be able to access that.

Comment: Even I add namespace also,I cannot use Session  in Console app?

Comment: @ShekharPankaj - I am not able to access any property of HttpClient.I am getting error" HttpClient is  a field but used like a method".

Comment: Try `System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();` instead.

Comment: nothing wrong with `httpClient` here,can you past your error stack here...
and before try using `HttpClientHandler Class`

Answer (score 1):

`Session` isn't available to Console applications.
It's an ASP.net *thing* - it resides server side.

When you access `Session` in an ASP.net application, all you're really doing is accessing the Session ID from the cookie that is sent with the request. The **server** then retrieves the Session object from the session store (in memory, in db, etc...) and makes it available to the **server side** application.

Your console app has no knowledge (nor should it) of any of this Session stuff.