# HTTP post XML data in C# with basic auth

Tags: c#, .net, xml, api, authentication

Iam set uping simple console application in c# for some API integration .I need to consume API with **POST Request with xml data** as request body and with **Basic Authentication**

I am able to consume api for retrival with Basic auth..But I am not sure how to consume api with post which having basic auth.

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210365/2932057

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer it shows the full android app including xml and java file 
link https://stackoverflow.com/a/57162854/11505004

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way I did. Using BASIC Authentication and XML data as the payload. Happy Coding :)

```
    SomeClass{
            private NetworkCredential credentials = null;
            private HttpClientHandler handler = null;                
            SomeClass(){ //Constructor
                  credentials = new NetworkCredential("ID", "PASS");
                  handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials};
                }  
        
     public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutMessage(your data) 
        {           
            var root= new
            {
                rootObj = data
            };    
            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
            var doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonObj); 
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;            
            try
            {   
                var httpContent = new StringContent(doc.InnerXml.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
                response = await httpClient.PostAsync(APIURL, httpContent);
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)                      
                    return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {               
                return "Return Error Message";
            }
        }
    }
```